# Sql Subselect count as where count is equal

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

Why I get 
Unknown column 'negavote' in 'where clause'

```
SELECT 
    my_users.name, 
    my_users.avatar, 
    my_users.surname, 
    fastmap_projects.*, 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `fastmap_rating` WHERE `fastmap_rating`.`map_id`=`fastmap_projects`.`id` AND `rate`='1') as `posivote`, 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `fastmap_rating` WHERE `fastmap_rating`.`map_id`=`fastmap_projects`.`id` AND `rate`='-1') as `negavote` 
FROM (`fastmap_projects`) 
    LEFT JOIN `my_users` ON `fastmap_projects`.`user_id`=`my_users`.`id` 
WHERE 
    `area_id` = '4' 
    AND (`negavote` BETWEEN -3 AND 3) 
    OR (`posivote` BETWEEN -3 AND 3)
```

Can you hint how can I change this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is your query, formatted so (at least) I can read it:

```
SELECT my_users.name, my_users.avatar, my_users.surname, fastmap_projects.*,
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM `fastmap_rating`
        WHERE `fastmap_rating`.`map_id`=`fastmap_projects`.`id` AND `rate`='1') as `posivote`,
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM `fastmap_rating`
        WHERE `fastmap_rating`.`map_id`=`fastmap_projects`.`id` AND `rate`='-1') as `negavote`
FROM `fastmap_projects` LEFT JOIN
     `my_users`
     ON `fastmap_projects`.`user_id`=`my_users`.`id`
WHERE `area_id` = '4' AND (`negavote` BETWEEN -3 AND 3) OR (`posivote` BETWEEN -3 AND 3)
```

You are trying to use a column alias in a `where` clause, and SQL does not allow this (this is part of the standard, not a MySQL limitation).  The normal solution is to use a subquery or CTE.  However, MySQL has an extension.  You can use the `having` clause instead of a `where` clause:

```
SELECT my_users.name, my_users.avatar, my_users.surname, fastmap_projects.*,
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM `fastmap_rating`
        WHERE `fastmap_rating`.`map_id`=`fastmap_projects`.`id` AND `rate`='1') as `posivote`,
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM `fastmap_rating`
        WHERE `fastmap_rating`.`map_id`=`fastmap_projects`.`id` AND `rate`='-1') as `negavote`
FROM `fastmap_projects` LEFT JOIN
     `my_users`
     ON `fastmap_projects`.`user_id`=`my_users`.`id`
HAVING `area_id` = '4' AND (`negavote` BETWEEN -3 AND 3) OR (`posivote` BETWEEN -3 AND 3);
```

As a note:  Just check your parentheses to be sure this is what you want to do.  This will choose areas that don't have id `4`.  You may mean this:

```
HAVING `area_id` = '4' AND (`negavote` BETWEEN -3 AND 3 OR `posivote` BETWEEN -3 AND 3);
```

Comment: thank you for your time. Now I got the problem. You saved my day

Answer (score 0):

You can't use column aliases in SQL where clause (except in PostgreSQL because that guy is smooth)

Either repeat the sub-select or wrap the query in a subquery and apply your filters on the upper query

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM (
  SELECT 
    my_users.NAME, 
    my_users.avatar, 
    my_users.surname, 
    fastmap_projects.*, 
    ( 
      SELECT Count(*) 
      FROM   `fastmap_rating` 
      WHERE  `fastmap_rating`.`map_id`=`fastmap_projects`.`id` 
      AND    `rate`='1'
    ) AS `posivote`, 
    ( 
      SELECT count(*) 
      FROM   `fastmap_rating` 
      WHERE  `fastmap_rating`.`map_id`=`fastmap_projects`.`id` 
      AND    `rate`='-1'
    ) AS `negavote` 
  FROM (`fastmap_projects`) 
  LEFT JOIN `my_users` ON `fastmap_projects`.`user_id`=`my_users`.`id` 
)
WHERE `area_id` = '4' 
AND (`negavote` BETWEEN -3 AND 3) 
OR (`posivote` BETWEEN -3 AND 3)
```